# Cannot insert item from dropdown menu into my database

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am new to C# and i am trying to insert some values to my database i created inside visual studio.

-I am creating a recipe application-
So in the form i have some components such as text boxes(For title,ingredients,description), a dropdown item(combobox) to specify if it's food or sweet and a button to insert all these data into my database.

When i am pressing the button i can add everything(all the text boxes) to the database except the dropdown value.

Here is the code inside the button_click

```
       private void addItemButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string dat = "Insert into [Table](Title,Category,Ingredients,Description) Values('" + titleTextBox.Text + "','" + dropdownCategory.SelectedValue + "','" + addIngredientTextBox.Text + "','" + addDescriptionTextBox.Text + "')";
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(dat, sqlCon);
        sqlCon.Open();
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlCon.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i don't know if it's correct or not but it worked on me.

I changed

`dropdownCategory.SelectedValue`

to

```
dropdownCategory.Text
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I make a code example, which can insert the combobox value to the database successfully.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string dat = string.Format("Insert into [Sample](Title,Category,Ingredients,Description)values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}')", textBox1.Text, comboBox1.SelectedItem,textBox2.Text,textBox3.Text);
            string connectionString = @"connectionstring";
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(dat, sqlCon);
            sqlCon.Open();
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlCon.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("success");
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] { "basketball","football", "volleyball" });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to look into content of string dat.
It might contain invalid data if "dropdownCategory.SelectedValue" returns something 
that you don't expect.

Other than that, order of Open(), ExecuteNonQuery() and Close() methods might be incorrect. Try to read docs of these methods.

Another thing that you should look into is error message that is returned(if there is one). They are usually pretty informative.

Comment: I put MessageBox.Show(dropdownCategory.SelectedValue.ToString()); 
to check the message and it gives me this error :

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.SelectedValue.get returned null.

Comment: It seems like dropdown doesn't contain value. I would add null check.
Something like dropdownCategory.SelectedValue!=null ? dropdownCategory.SelectedValue : "default value"; should work.